Android Studio - Jetpack Compose Kotlin circular scroller input time selection
Hi I'm new to android and I've been trying to implement a circular scroller for time selection as an input field in a form -

I am having a weird issue where the index value keeps changing by +1 after selection. For example if I select "1:05 PM", the selected value ends up changing to "2:06 AM".
 
I'm not sure why but I can see by logging the index change and value change it is firing several times.
This is what I have so far (stripped of irrelevant parts) -
Main composable:
@Composable
fun AddNewScreen(viewModel: SomeViewModel) {
    val timeViewModel: TimeViewModel = viewModel()
    var showStartTime by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    var selectedStartTimeObj = viewModel.startTime.observeAsState()
    var selectedStartTime = selectedStartTimeObj.value

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures(onTap = {
                    if (showStartTime) {
                        showStartTime = false
                    }
                })
            }
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {

        if (selectedStartTime != null) {
            TimeScrollInput(
                showStartTime,
                toggleShow = { showStartTime = it },
                selectedStartTime,
                onSelected = { viewModel.updateTime(true, it) },
                timeViewModel
            )
        }

    }
}

Lower level composables:
 @Composable
    fun TimeScrollInput(
        show: Boolean = false,
        toggleShow: (Boolean) -> Unit,
        selectedTime: Time,
        onSelected: (Time) -> Unit,
        viewModel: TimeViewModel
    ) {
        if (show) {
            selectedTime?.let { it ->
                TimeSelectionScrollerStart(
                    time = it,
                    timeSelection = {
                        onSelected(it)
                    },
                    viewModel
                )
            }
        }
        else {
            Text(
                selectedTime.hour + ":" + selectedTime.minute + " " + selectedTime.meridiem,
                modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                    toggleShow(true)
                })
        }
    }


    @Composable
    fun TimeSelectionScrollerStart(
        time: Time,
        timeSelection: (Time) -> Unit,
        timeViewModel: TimeViewModel
    ) {
    
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
    
            InfiniteCircularList(
                width = 30.dp,
                itemHeight = 40.dp,
                items = timeViewModel.hours,
                initialItem = time.hour,
                textColor = Color.Gray,
                selectedTextColor = colorResource(R.color.violet)
            ) { itemSelected ->
                timeSelection(Time(itemSelected, time.minute, time.meridiem))
            }
    
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))
    
            Text(":")
    
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))
    
            InfiniteCircularList(
                width = 30.dp,
                itemHeight = 40.dp,
                items = timeViewModel.minutes,
                initialItem = time.minute,
                textColor = Color.Gray,
                selectedTextColor = colorResource(R.color.violet)
            ) { itemSelected ->
                timeSelection(Time(time.hour, itemSelected, time.meridiem))
            }
    
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(6.dp))
    
            InfiniteCircularList(
                width = 30.dp,
                itemHeight = 40.dp,
                items = timeViewModel.meridiem,
                initialItem = time.meridiem,
                textColor = Color.Gray,
                selectedTextColor = colorResource(R.color.violet)
            ) { itemSelected ->
                timeSelection(Time(time.hour, time.minute, itemSelected))
            }
    
        }
    }

Circular scroller composable template (code I found when searching for a solution.):
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun <T> InfiniteCircularList(
    width: Dp,
    itemHeight: Dp,
    numberOfDisplayedItems: Int = 3,
    items: List<T>,
    initialItem: T,
    textColor: Color,
    selectedTextColor: Color,
    onItemSelected: (index: Int, item: T) -> Unit = { _, _ -> },
    itemSelected: (String) -> Unit
) {
    val itemHalfHeight = LocalDensity.current.run { itemHeight.toPx() / 2f }
    val scrollState = rememberLazyListState(0)
    var lastSelectedIndex by rememberSaveable {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }
    var itemsState by remember {
        mutableStateOf(items)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        var targetIndex = items.indexOf(initialItem) - 1
        targetIndex += ((Int.MAX_VALUE / 2) / items.size) * items.size
        itemsState = items
        lastSelectedIndex = targetIndex
        scrollState.scrollToItem(targetIndex)
        Log.d(TAG, "launch effect last selected index, $lastSelectedIndex")
        Log.d(TAG, "launch effect target index, $targetIndex")
    }

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(width)
            .height(itemHeight * numberOfDisplayedItems),
        state = scrollState,
        flingBehavior = rememberSnapFlingBehavior(
            lazyListState = scrollState
        )
    ) {
        items(
            count = Int.MAX_VALUE,
            itemContent = { i ->
                val item = itemsState[i % itemsState.size]
                Log.d(TAG, "item val first initialize, item = $item")
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(itemHeight)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                            val y = coordinates.positionInParent().y - itemHalfHeight
                            val parentHalfHeight = (itemHalfHeight * numberOfDisplayedItems)
                            val isSelected =
                                (y > parentHalfHeight - itemHalfHeight && y < parentHalfHeight + itemHalfHeight)
                            val index = i - 1
                            if (isSelected && lastSelectedIndex != index) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "before setting onItemSelected, item = $item")
                                onItemSelected(index % itemsState.size, item)
                                Log.d(TAG, "before setting itemSelected, item = $item")
                                itemSelected(item.toString())
                                lastSelectedIndex = index
                            }
                        },
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {

                    Text(
                        text = item.toString(),
                        color = if (lastSelectedIndex == i) {
                            selectedTextColor
                        } else {
                            textColor
                        },
                        fontSize = if (lastSelectedIndex == i) {
                            16.sp
                        } else {
                            14.sp
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

"SomeViewModel":
class SomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

private val _startTime = MutableLiveData<Time>(Time("12", "00", "AM"))
var startTime: LiveData<Time> = _startTime

fun updateTime(start: Boolean, time: Time) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Updating time!! - $time")
        if(start) {
            _startTime.value = time
        }
        else {
            //_endTime.value = time
        }
    }
}

TimeViewModel:
class TimeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val hours =
        mutableStateListOf<String>()
            .apply {
                IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 12)
                    .forEach { hr ->
                        add(hr.toString())
                    }
            }

    val minutes =
        mutableStateListOf<String>()
            .apply {
                IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 59)
                    .forEach { min ->
                        if (min < 10) {
                            add(min.toString().padStart(2, '0'))
                        } else {
                            add(min.toString())
                        }
                    }
            }

    val meridiem =
        mutableStateListOf<String>()
            .apply {
                add("AM")
                add("PM")
            }
}

Time() data class:
data class Time(
    val hour : String = "12",
    val minute : String = "00",
    val meridiem : String = "PM"
)

Any ideas on why this is happening?

There is an error in InfiniteCircularList implementation. It returns the item at index i % itemsState.size but should return one at index (i - 1) % itemsState.size. To fix replace the line:
itemSelected(item.toString())

with:
val selectedItem = itemsState[index % itemsState.size]
itemSelected(selectedItem.toString())

Same goes for onItemSelected, if you need it.

Hi thanks so much for the reply, that did the trick.

The problem is that you are calling the callback function in onGloballyPositioned method. If you pay attention to the logs, the callback is called two times, first with the correct value and second with the other one. That is caused by the recomposition.
I suggest you to extract that logic from the position function so it can be agnostic of the place where it is the composable.

Hi thanks for the reply. I see what you're saying but I'm not sure how to apply it to my situation since I need the onGloballyPositioned and other values from that composable
